# Crear VPN con modem CISCO

Tags: vpn

estaba intentando crear una red VPN con mi módem cisco y la verdad que no sabría muy bien como poder crearla. Entre al módem y me tope con estos datos al querer crear el túnel.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿En la parte de "Local endpoint settings" configuraría todo lo relacionado a lo que esta dentro de mi red local verdad? Por ejemplo, mi red es 192.168.0.0/24, entonces en subnet podría 192.168.0.0 con una mask 255.255.255.0 no? Mi mayor duda acá es que es Identity, la verdad que no se que poner ahí, ¿el gateway?

Luego, en la parte de "Remote endpoint settings" me perdí mas. Creería que en la parte del "Remote Address" va mi IP WAN, pero en los demás campos no sabría que poner, mas que nada porque se repite lo se la sub red.

Por favor, si podrían ayudarme, lo agradecería mucho.

Comment: Una pregunta, con esa pantalla lo que vas es a crear una conexión túnel entre dos redes, en este caso, las dos redes deben tener dos router "similares" e IP publicas fijas. Eso es lo que quieres? o quieres que desde cualquier ordenador se puedan conectar a tu red?

Comment: Lo segundo, que desde cualquier IP sea publica o no, se puedan conectar a mi red.

Answer (score 0):

Entonces no es en esa pantalla donde tienes que configurarlo. Tienes dos posibles opciones.
1 (no sé si tú router puedes hacerlo) busca una opción que es servidor PPP y es simplemente activarlo crear un usuario y contraseña. No es una opción que todos los router tengan.
2. Necesitas
I. configurar un equipo para recibir conexiones o si es un servidor Windows instalar enrutamiento y acceso remoto (de Linux ni idea)
II. Configurar el firewall para permitir las conexiones o puerto 1723
III. En el router redirigir el puerto 1723 al equipo o servidor

Obviamente la opción 1 es mucho más sencilla, pero de debe de tenerla al router.

Saludos

Comment: A genial, muchísimas gracias, me re servio el consejo. Si, tenia la idea de hacer un servidor en un ordenador, pero como estoy medio corto de tiempo preferí utilizar la opción del módem que era mucho mas simple.